# c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-fast'

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile graphlab on a Mac.

-fast appears to be some special optimizer setting.

The Mac is running OS X 10.9.4 Mavericks.

```
   $ uname -a
    Darwin David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro.local 13.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.3.0: Tue Jun  3 21:27:35 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.110.17~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

    $ g++ --version
    g++ (MacPorts gcc48 4.8.3_0) 4.8.3
```

...

```
============================================================
libjson version: 7.6.0 target:  OS: Darwin
============================================================
c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-fast'
make[3]: *** [Objects_static/internalJSONNode.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [../deps/json/src/libjson-stamp/libjson-build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/libjson.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

A few Google searches suggested I'm missing libcm.
There's a link to Gnome for libcm, which doesn't seem to show anything about libcm.
But, nothing in Macports.

Comment: I don't think `-fast` has anything to do with libraries.  Where did the g++ command come from?  Do you have the g++ command graphlab's build generated?

Comment: It looks like `-fast` is specific to Sun's C compiler (see: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/1999-09n/msg00152.html) It shouldn't be used on the `g++` command on the Mac.

Comment: I first ran ./configure then make.  Would you like to see config.log, or -rw-r--r--   1 davidlaxer  staff  20614 Sep  6 18:17 CMakeCache.txt
drwxr-xr-x  27 davidlaxer  staff    918 Sep  6 18:18 CMakeFiles
-rw-r--r--   1 davidlaxer  staff    349 Sep  5 09:33 CTestTestfile.cmake
-rw-r--r--   1 davidlaxer  staff  62406 Sep  6 18:18 Makefile

Comment: Where did you get the GraphLab source tree?

Comment: I see you posted to the forums on the graphlab.org site, which is good.  I tried building on my machine, but the build found the `clang` compiler instead of `g++`.  `clang` only issues a warning about `-fast`, but not an error, so the build continues.  However, the build did crash because it couldn't find `<omp.h>` That's all I've been able to get to so far... hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks!  Perhaps we're the first to try building GraphLab on Mavericks.